# Simple guide or documentation to deploy a simple local web page using Python to be acessed by other devices on the network

Tags: python, django, web-services, raspberry-pi, web2py

I've searched through similar questions but couldn't find an answer to this particular problem. Here's my goal:

- Make a web page that's available through the network e.g. http://192.168.1.20:8080
- I'll use a Raspberry Pi as server, and it will refresh the page at each 60 seconds
- My goal is to refresh 4 variables using some input(don't  worry about how) and display their values

I have some experience with tkinter if it's of any use in this application.I want to do this in Python because it's a language I already use for various uses. Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this in Python without any other lib dependencies is to use the built in SimpleHTTPServer. You can run the below command to server the files from the current directory

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Then you can access any file from the directory you are serving with the command above by going to `http://yourip:8080/yourfile.html`